# Only allow specific requests by checking referer?

Tags: spring, security, request, http-referer

I check a critical request from a controller like this:

```
final String referer = request.getHeader("referer");
if (isEmpty(referer) || !referer.contains("/foo/bar")) {
    //Redirect
}
```

Since the request can only be sent from `/foo/bar`. But will this add some meaningful security?

Edit :
I forgot to mention that the requests are sent by signed in users. But I'm curious if I can add more security like this.

Comment: What is the purpose? External attacker can set up attacker.com/foo/bar. Anybody can send any referer if client is not a browser (and under special circumstances, from a browser too, consider for example old or malicious browser plugins).

Comment: @Gabor So the answer is no. I already thought so, but I was wondering if I missed some benefits. Thank you.

Comment: I was really wondering what you were trying to achieve. If it's for some kind of access control, then no, it is not sufficient.

Comment: @Gabor Yes, it's for access control. I don't know about security though. I guess that's why I am poking around. I got curious and googled but no information about `referer`, so I asked in here. But it seems this is meaningless and just using login check is sufficient.